# Saving Data with DataMapper

Tags: ruby, orm, datamapper

I'm trying to save to a sqlite 3 database. I can't seem to save, but no errors are thrown. What am I doing wrong? I took the save routine from a preexisting piece of code of mine that works. Any ideas on what I should try next?

```
require 'data_mapper'
require 'dm-migrations'

DataMapper.setup :default, "sqlite://#{Dir.pwd}/development.sqlite3"

class Post
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :title,      String, :key => true # An auto-increment integer key
  property :slug_url,   String   
  property :desc,       String
  property :content,    String
  property :project,    String
  property :target_url, String
  property :trackback,  Boolean
  property :updated_at, String
  property :created_at, DateTime  # A DateTime, for any date you might like.
end

DataMapper.finalize
DataMapper.auto_upgrade!

post = Post.new
post.attributes = {:title => "Title",
                :slug_url => "Some-slug-url",
                :content => "content",
                :target_url => "http://example.com",
                :trackback => false
}
post.save
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this works any differently, but I got it to work by doing this:

```
require 'data_mapper'
require 'dm-migrations'

DataMapper.setup :default, "sqlite://#{Dir.pwd}/development.sqlite3"

class Post
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :title,      String, :key => true # An auto-increment integer key
  property :slug_url,   String    # A varchar type string, for short strings
  property :desc,       String
  property :content,    String
  property :project,    String
  property :target_url, String
  property :trackback,  Boolean
  property :updated_at, DateTime
  property :created_at, DateTime  # A DateTime, for any date you might like.
end

DataMapper.finalize
DataMapper.auto_upgrade!

post = Post.new(:title => "Title",
                    :slug_url => "Some-slug-url",
                    :content => "content",
                    :target_url => "http://example.com",
                    :trackback => false)
post.save
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'no errors are thrown' part can be fixed with `DataMapper::Model.raise_on_save_failure = true`, `DataMapper` doesn't bail by default. `#save!` is the unsafe version (no idea why `ActiveRecord` uses totally different semantics for the bang). [For further information, read here.](http://datamapper.org/docs/create_and_destroy.html)

The first error thrown was `column title is not unique (DataObjects::IntegrityError)`. Guess what happend ;-)